# jQuery: Making a Plugin Wait Until Existing Calls Are Done To Execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I should begin by saying that, while I'm pretty familiar with basic JavaScript/jQuery, I'm by no means an expert. So this could be a simple concept I'm not grasping. At any rate, I'll explain my situation as best I can.

I have been piecing together a jQuery plugin that takes a string and displays it one character at a time until the end of the string has been reached. Each call starts and stops on an interval as needed until done:

```
$.fn.writeText = function(content) {
    var elem = this;
    var contentArray = content.split("");

    return this.each(function() {
        var current = 0;
        var length = contentArray.length;
    intervalText();     

    function intervalText(){
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(current < length){   
            //If end punctuation is detected [omitted for simplicity's sake]
            {
            elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++],play('tes.wav'));
            clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeout(function(){intervalText();},500);
            }
            //Else if 'pause' punctuation is detected.
            {
                elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++],play('tes.wav'));
                clearInterval(interval);
                setTimeout(function (){intervalText();},200);
            }
            else{
                elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++],play('tes.wav'));
                }
        }
        else if(current == length+1){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 50);
    }
    });
}
```

One thing I've noticed is that using the plugin back to back causes problems:

```
$("#promptText").writeText("This test.");
$("#promptText").writeText("This is also a test.");
//Results in "TThhiiss tiess ta.lso a test."
```

I determined pretty quickly that the issue is just that characters are being added to the same element, and that the plugin isn't doing anything "wrong." But, as you can imagine I'd like to prevent this from happening.

In order to do that, I'd need to cause any secondary calls to the plugin to wait until the previous ones were finished. Any suggestions as to how I'd go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great application for jQuery's [Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects. Deferreds let you start a function, then chain additional calls after that function completes (the $.ajax() function uses Deferreds internally).

In this case, you can queue up a new Deferred each time you call $().writeText(), and make them call your internal function in order:

```
var deferred;
$.fn.writeText = function (content) {
    var d = $.Deferred(); //Each execution gets its own deferred
    var elem = this;
    var f = function () {
        writeTextInternal(content, elem, d); //Do it
    }
    if (deferred) { //If there is already a deferred, queue the new request
        deferred.then(f); //Calls f() when deferred is resolved, or immediately if already resolved
    } else {
        f(); //Call immediately, because there are no deferreds
    }
    deferred = d.promise(); //Save this deferred to chain subsequent calls.
    return deferred; //Allows other functions to do something after this text is typed.
}

var writeTextInternal = function(content, elem, d) {
    //Slightly modified original function that will resolve our deferred...
}
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bt5tee3r/3/

Comment: I'm noticing that this only seems to work for the two. If I want to throw in any calls after this, it goes back to the original behaviour after waiting on the first call. It seems that the first deferred object created pends and resolves normally. But subsequent calls pend and resolve concurrently. Is there a way to correct this? I've tried myself, but to be honest I'm not even sure if that is the problem.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the code above to resolve the issue; we needed to save the deferred call during $.fn.writeText() rather than before the call to writeTextInternal.